# Javascript onclick action not working on image or icon

Tags: javascript, html

I've found a simple javascript onclick function below.

```js
  
    function dropdownFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    
    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
      <button onclick="dropdownFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When I try the below html code, dropdown content doesn't pop up.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropbtn" onclick="dropdownFunction()">
    <%= image_tag "global-icon.png", alt: 'Language' %>
    <i class="icon-down-dir"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please advise what I'm missing or wrong.

**Updates**

I changed to jquery instead and it's working flawlessly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#droptoggle').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
         $("#myDropdown").slideToggle("1000");
    });
    $("#myDropdown").on("click", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
//close when click out of window
$(document).on("click", function () {
    $("#myDropdown").hide();
});
```

Comment: In the first line of your `window.onclick` function,  can you `console.log(event.target);` and see what the result is? That should tell you if the correct element is receiving your click.

Comment: After adding the console code,  I'm aware of that when I'm clicking image, onclick function doesn't respond. But it does on the texts. So, my question is still at the same point. Do you have any idea of this issue?

Comment: Try `window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {})` instead of `window.onclick = function(event) {}`

Comment: @HVD  It still doesn't respond on click image but does on the text.

Comment: Can you upload the full code to jsfiddle include css too? Maybe you have trouble with z-index.

Comment: I didn't want to spend more time so I changed jquery and it's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function dropdownFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myDropdown {
  display: none;
}

#myDropdown.show
{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="dropdownFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

added CSS part here,